# What is the difference between the "chemistry" and "astrochemistry" tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Both the [chemistry](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) and [astrochemistry](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrochemistry) tags have over a dozen questions.

However there are only four questions that have both tags, and three of those are mine, probably in anticipation that they might be merged in the future.

- Do we need both as tags?
- If so, what is the difference?
- If not, should they be merged?

Here are questions that are tagged [chemistry](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry), categorized by how well I estimate that [astrochemistry](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrochemistry) would suffice and a separate [chemistry](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) tag would not be needed. I'm wondering if "chemistry" is even the proper tag or something like "geochemistry" or "planetary-chemistry" might be a better name for it.

---

[astrochemistry](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrochemistry) tag will probably suffice:

- [Have caged molecules ever been observed in space?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/31649/7982) unless Rob Jeffries’ “clathrates” end up being on/inside planets
- [Why was helium hydride (HeH+) the universe's first molecule?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/30533/7982)
- [What is the organic material in Saturn's rings?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/30091/7982)
- [Is the composition of stars in future made of more and more heavy elements?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/16380/7982)
- [What is the distribution of organic compounds in the Milky Way Galaxy?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/14170/7982)
- [What happens to oxygen produced on the Sun (or other stars)?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/12381/7982)
- [Why are there no green stars?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/10510/7982)
- [Why is there so much methane in space?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/10091/7982)
- [Internal heat and planetary differentiation](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/10016/7982)

Not sure, depends on what [astrochemistry](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrochemistry) means:

- [Is there any difference among exoplanets in composition due to host star?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26287/7982)
- [What is germane doing in the atmosphere of Jupiter?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/21378/7982)
- [What aliphatic compounds were found on Ceres, and how where they identified?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/20081/7982)
- [What factors influence the Widmanstätten pattern in iron meteorites?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/19129/7982)

[astrochemistry](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrochemistry) probably not the proper tag:

- [What could be the possible origin of boron found in the Martian soil if not from ancient groundwater?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/19440/7982)
- [Massive degraded impact crater on Mercury - chemical evidence?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18976/7982)
- [Statistics of elements abundance in exoplanets](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/10097/7982)
- [Can a planet with a hydrogen atmosphere have a water ocean with dissolved oxygen? (closed)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/19627/7982)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think we need both tags. I suggest merging the [chemistry](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) questions into [astrochemistry](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrochemistry), as we have [astrobiology](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrobiology) but no biology tag. I don't think we should create a synonym between chemistry and astrochemistry though. [chemistry](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) only has four uses this year, so I don't think it will be a big deal to retag manually in the future. That said, we should keep our eyes out for questions that use [chemistry](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) for questions that are not related to astrochemistry (e.g. planetary geochemistry). If we have any of those, we should keep the chemistry tag and add a tag wiki to clarify its use.

Comment: for my own reference (I can't keep them straight): [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710/303080) I'll check the existing `chemistry` questions for non-astrochemistry instances, msg here if I find any.

Comment: @uhoh Did you see any non-astrochemistry instances?

Comment: yes I saw quite a mix, and decided it's best to look at all of them to see what the pattern is. Then got distracted. I'll review them all in the morning. Thanks for the ping.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: @uhoh I think for the purpose of this site, the "not sure" section can be considered astrochemistry. One of the four "not astrochemistry" questions is closed, so that really only leaves three to be concerned about. Is that enough to justify the continued existence of a chemistry tag? Particularly, those three questions are all more than two years old. Maybe we should just untag the four outliers and merge the rest.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean. Given all of that, it seems like a good idea. Even if askers start typing "chem..." the astrochemistry tag will immediately appear for them.

Comment: @uhoh All right, the changes are done. [tag:chemistry] should have no questions on it now. We'll just have to make sure it doesn't get used again and it should eventually disappear.

Comment: wow that was quick! yes, it shows empty for me. Thanks for your help.